# What's gone wrong with my regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z/._\-\s]/',$user)
```

I am getting

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '.' in F:\wamp\www\distinctive\include\validate.inc.php on line 4

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` in the regex:

```
preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z\/._\-\s]/',$user)
```

or use a different delimiter:

```
preg_match('#[^0-9A-Za-z/._\-\s]#',$user)
```

Otherwise, the `/` matches the delimiter at the beginning, and everything after it is considered a modifier.